# launch Process in windows mobile

Tags: process, windows-mobile

i want to launch a application from ather application ;
the code

```
`public static void RunProcess(string AppProcessName)
        {
            string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(AppProcessName);
            foreach (string file in Files)
            {
                if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file).Equals(".exe"))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process AppProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo Info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                    Info.FileName = file.Replace('/', '\\');
                    AppProcess.StartInfo = Info;
                    AppProcess.Start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }`
```

but i get a exception win32Exception

Comment: What does the exception message say?  What is the exact FileName you're ending up with?  And you can run the other app by just tapping its icon in Explorer, yes (i.e. it's a valid WinMo app and app of its dependencies are there)?

Answer (score 0):

The `.exe` file you are trying to run is not a Windows Mobile application. Just because you can copy it to the Windows Mobile device does not mean it can run on Windows Mobile.

Comment: it a application windows mobile; now i try to programme a system to  updated automatictly   

i try it manuely and it runing correctly

Comment: Instead of using a loop, have you tried declaring the name of the `exe` file directly? (eliminate the possibility that something was passed in wrong)